# Rails ActiveRecord Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

I'm using ActiveRecord Session Store and I have a few questions regarding using this store.

I can easily create a model for accessing any session directly (from the console, not as a controller or anything):

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I can then access and decode the contents of sessions, for example

```
Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(Session.first)
```

But I'm curious why I can't seem to find many other people doing this sort of thing? At the very least, I would at least want to have a job to delete expired sessions, so the sessions table doesn't grow and grow. I also store several fields in sessions which are important to the application logic. It is conceivable that I might at some point want to perform some maintenance task with logic based on decoded session data. Is this sort of storage a design taboo?

I'm hoping that someone who has more experience managing a production rails application could take a stab at some or these questions, or at least share how they are using sessions.

Thanks.

edit: I just realized that the session data store is Base64 encoded, and not encrypted in any way.

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't recommend  storing data in the cookie. Look at ActiveRecord store for sessions. It stores a key in the user's cookie that references back to a record in the db.

Comment: Thanks, this is the store that I am currently using.